# Need to validate with javascript, php, update the DB table and redirect to login

Tags: javascript, php, sql, session

Trying to get my customer registration page for a hotel database to validate the input with javascript then php, and update the database with the new customers info and redirect them to the correct login page (customerlogin). 
When i click submit, state, telephone, country, suburb, title go blank and the other feilds remain with the info entered.
Please help thanks

```
<?php
require_once("dbconn.php");
$username = $pwrd = $repwrd = $gname = $sname = $addr = $suburb = $state = $ptcode = $mobile = $email = "";
$usernameErr = $pwrdErr = $repwrdErr = $gnameErr = $snameErr = $addrErr = $suburbErr = $stateErr = $ptcodeErr = $mobileErr = $emailErr = "";

//when the form is being submitted
if (isset($_POST["submit"]))
{
    $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbConn, $_POST["uname"]);
    if (empty($username))
        $usernameErr = '<span class="error">Please enter a Unique ID</span>';
    else {
        $Npattern = "/^[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,20}+$/";
        if (!preg_match($Npattern, $username))
        {
            $usernameErr = '<span class="error">Username already exists!</span>';
        }
         }

    $pwrd = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbConn, $_POST["pword"]);
    if (empty($pwrd))
        $pwrdErr = '<span class="error">Please enter a password</span>';
    else {
        $PWpattern = "/^[a-zA-Z0-9]{6,20}+$/";
        if ( !preg_match($PWpattern, $pwrd))
        {
            $pwrdErr = '<span class="error">Password must be minimum of 6 characters</span>';
        }
    }

    $repwrd = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbConn, $_POST["pword2"]);
    if ( empty($repwrd))
        $repwrdErr = '<span class="error">Please ensure passwords match</span>';
    else {
        $pwrd = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbConn, $_POST["pword"]);
        if (! $repwrd == $pwrd )
        {
            $repwrdErr = '<span class="error">Passwords do not match</span>';
        }
    }

    $gname = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbConn, $_POST["FName"]);
    if (empty($gname))
        $gnameErr = '<span class="error">Please enter your First Name</span>';
    else {
        $Gpattern = "/^[a-zA-Z .\-]{1,20}+$/";
        if ( !preg_match($Gpattern, $gname))
        {
            $gnameErr = '<span class="error">First Name can only contain alphabetical letters, spaces, hyphens and apostrophe';
            $gnameErr .= 'it also must not exceed 20 characters</span>';
        }
    }

    $sname = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbConn, $_POST["LName"]);
    if (empty($sname))
        $snameErr = '<span class="error">Please enter Last Name</span>';
    else {
        $Fpattern = "/^[a-zA-Z .\-]{1,20}+$/";
        if ( !preg_match($Fpattern, $sname))
        {
            $snameErr = '<span class="error">Family Name can only contain alphabetical letters, spaces, hyphens and apostrophe';
            $snameErr .= 'it also must not exceed 20 characters</span>';
        }
    }

    $addr = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbConn, $_POST["add"]);
    if (empty($addr))
        $addrErr = '<span class="error">Please enter Address</span>';
    else {
        if (strlen($addr) > 40 )
        {
            $addrErr = '<span class="error">Your Address must not exceed 40 characters long </span>';
        }
    }

    $state = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbConn, $_POST["state"]);
    if ($state == "--" )
        $stateErr = '<span class="error"> Please enter state</span>';


    $ptcode = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbConn, $_POST["pcode"]);
    if (empty($ptcode))
        $ptcodeErr = '<span class="error">Please enter postcode</span>';
    else {
        $pcPattern = "/^[0-9]{4}$/";
        if (!preg_match($pcPattern,$ptcode))
        $ptcodeErr = '<span class="error">Postcode must be 4 digits</span>';
         }

    $mobile = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbConn, $_POST["mobile"]);
    if (empty($mobile))
        $mobileErr = '<span class="error">Please enter mobile number</span>';
    else {
        $Mobilepattern = "/^04?\d{8}$/";
        if (!preg_match($Mobilepattern, $mobile))
        $mobileErr = '<span class="error">Mobile number must be 10 digits</span>';
         }

    $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbConn, $_POST["email"]);
    if (empty($email))
        $emailErr = '<span class="error">Please Enter email address</span>';
    else {
        if ( filter_var($email,FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
        {
            $emailErr = '<span class="error">Email not Valid</span>';
        }
    }
}
else if (isset($_POST["reset"]))
{
    unset($_POST["username"]);
    unset($_POST["password"]);
    unset($_POST["repassword"]);
    unset($_POST["gname"]);
    unset($_POST["sname"]);
    unset($_POST["address"]);
    unset($_POST["state"]);
    unset($_POST["postcode"]);
    unset($_POST["mobile"]);
    unset($_POST["email"]);
    unset($_POST[""]);
}

?>



<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Registration Form</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css">

    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" >
    function validateUsername(uname)
    {
        var uname = document.getElementById("uname").value;
        if (uname.length < 21) {
            return true;
        } else {
            Alert("Please choose a username with a max of 20 characters");
            return false;
        }
    }

    function validatePword(input)
    {
        var pword = document.getElementById("pword").value;
        if (pword.length > 6) {
            return true;
                        } 
        else 
        {
            alert("Please choose a Password between 6 and 20 characters");
            return false;
        }
        if (pword.length < 20) {
            return true;
        } else {
              alert("Please choose a Password between 6 and 20 characters");
             }
        }


    function confirmPword(input)
    {
        var pword = document.getElementById("pword").value;
        var pword2 = document.getElementById("pword2").value;
        if (pword2 == pword){
            return true;
            }
        else 
        {
            alert("Passwords do not match, please retype password in both feilds.");
             }  
    }

    function validateName(txt) {
        var letters = /^[A-Za-z-']+$/;
        if (txt.value.match(letters)) {
            return true;
        } else {
            alert("Invalid Characters Entered for Name")
            return false;
        }
    }

    function validateAdd(input) {
        var add = document.getElementById("add").value;
        if (add.length < 41) {
            return true;
        } else {
              alert("Address must not be more then 40 characters");
             }
        }

    function validatePcode(input) {
        var pcode = document.getElementById("pcode").value;
        var numbers = "123456789";
        if (pcode.length < 4) { 
            alert("Postcode must be 4 digits")
        }
        else {
            if (pcode.value.match(numbers)){
                return true;
                }
        }
    }

    function validatePhone(input) {
        var phoneNo = /^\d{10}$/;

        if (input.value.match(phoneNo)) {
            return true;
        } else {
            alert("Phone number must be in the format of 04xxxxxxxx");
        }
    }

    function validateEmail(input) {
        var email = input.value;

        if (email.indexOf("@") > -1 && email.indexOf(".") > -1) {
            return true;
        } else {
            alert("Please enter a valid email address");
            return false;
        }
    }


    </script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css">
</head>
<body>
<form id="regForm" name="regForm" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars ($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?>" method="post" onsubmit="return confirmPword();">

<div id="header">
    <h1>Western Sydney Hotel</h1>
</div>

    <h1>Register as a User</h1>
    <p> Please fill out the form below to register for the hotel website. </p>

    <hr>        
    <h2>Account Details</h2>

    <b>Username</b>
    <input type= "text" name="uname" id="uname" size="20" maxlength="20" onblur="validateUsername(this);" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($username); ?>">
<br><br>

    <b>Password</b>
    <input type= "password" name="pword" id="pword" size="20" maxlength="20" min="6" onblur="validatePword(this);" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($pwrd); ?>">

    <b>Retype password</b>
    <input type= "password" name="pword2" id="pword2" size="20" maxlength="20" min="6" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($repwrd); ?>">    
<br>
<hr>    

    <h2>Personal Details</h2>

    <p>
    <b>Title:</b>
<br>
    <select name="Title"  required>
        <option value=" "></option>
        <option value="Dr">Dr</option>
        <option value="Mr">Mr</option>
        <option value="Mrs">Mrs</option>
        <option value="Ms">Ms</option>
        <option value="Miss">Miss</option>
    </select>
    </p>

    <p><b>First Name:</b><br> <input type= "text" name="FName" id="FName" size="20" maxlength="20" onblur="validateName(this);" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($gname); ?>" /></p>

    <p><b>Family Name:</b><br> <input type="text" name="LName" id="LName" size="20" maxlength="20" onblur="validateName(this);" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($sname); ?>" /></p>
<hr>

    <h2>Contact Details</h2>

    <p><b>Street Address:</b><br> <input type="Text" Name="add" id="add" size="40" maxlength="40" onblur="validateAdd(this);" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($addr); ?>" /></p>

    <p><b>Suburb:</b><br> <input type="text" name ="Suburb" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($suburb); ?>" /></p>

    <p><b>State:</b><br> <select name ="state" id="state" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($state); ?>" >
        <option value=" ">  </option>
        <option value="nsw"> NSW </option>
        <option value="wa"> WA </option>
        <option value="sa"> SA </option>
        <option value="vic"> VIC </option>
        <option value="qld"> QLD </option>
        <option value="nt"> NT </option>
        <option value="act"> ACT </option>
        </p>
        </select>

<br>
    <p><b>Country:</b><br> <input type="text" name ="country" /></p>

    <p><b>Postcode:</b> <br><input type="Text" size="4" maxlength="4" name="pcode" id="pcode" onblur="validatePostcode(this);" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($ptcode); ?>"/> </p>

    <p><b>Telephone:</b><br> <input type="Tel" name="Telephone" /></p>

    <p><b>Mobile:</b><br> <input type="text" name="mobile" id="mobile" onblur="validatePhone(this);" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($mobile); ?>" /></p>

    <p><b>Email:</b><br> <input type="Email" name="email" maxlength="40" onblur="validateEmail(this);" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($email); ?>" /></p>
<br>
<hr>

<input type="Submit" name="submit" value="Submit"/>
<input type="Reset"  name ="reset" value="Reset"/>

<br>
<br>

<div id="footer">
Copyright © Western Sydney Hotels
</div>


</form>
<?php
    require_once("dbconn.php");
if (isset($_POST["submit"]) && strlen($usernameErr)==0 && strlen($pwrdErr)==0 && strlen($repwrdErr)==0 && strlen($gnameErr)==0 && strlen($snameErr)==0
                            && strlen($addrErr)==0 && strlen($stateErr)==0 && strlen($ptcodeErr)==0 && strlen($mobileErr)==0 && strlen($emailErr)==0)
{
    $sql = "INSERT INTO customers(username, password, gname, sname, address, state, postcode, mobile, email)
            VALUES ('$username', '$pwrd', '$gname', '$sname', '$addr', '$state', '$ptcode', '$mobile', '$email')";

if (mysqli_query($dbConn, $sql))
{
    echo "Registration for  Western Sydney Hotels complete";
    header("location: customerlogin.php");
}
else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($dbConn);
     }
}
mysqli_close($dbConn);
die();
?>
</body>
</HTML>
```